Create a Machine Learning Numpy array with scalar features and an N-dimensional Coordinate Vector feature
I'm trying to format my data for a ML program. There are 33,000 events and each event has 3 things I want to consider: Mass, Energy, a coordinate.
The Mass is of the shape (33000,) and looks like: [188.9 189.0 125.7 ... 127.4 201.0 210.1].
Energy is also (33000,) and looks the same: [1 2 3 ... 8 9 10]. I then also have a 10-dimensional coordinate vector of the shape (33000,10)
Each coordinate is a 10-dimensional vector containing 10 coordinate points:
Coordinate Array:
    [[19.9 613.0 6.5 127.4 486.4 54.3 194.0 19.4 194.0 32.3]
    [1.89 1.01 4.9 ... 2.3 2.3 2.3]
    [1.2 6.1 4.0 ... 1.7 1.7 1.7]
    ...
    ]

I want to feed these into a machine-learning program. However, I don't want to create an array that squashes the 10-dimensional coordinate into a flat set of float values that looks like:
  [188.9 1 19.9 613.0 6.5 127.4 486.4 54.3 194.0 19.4 194.0 32.3\]
  [189.0 2 1.89 1.01 4.9 ... 2.3 2.3 2.3\]
  ...

This would lose the information that the last 10 values are intrinsically tied together, as they are a coordinate. Instead, I would like to create a numpy array that has a vector in the middle of the array
  [188.9 1 [19.9 613.0 6.5 127.4 486.4 54.3 194.0 19.4 194.0 32.3]]
  [189.0 2 [1.89 1.01 4.9 ... 2.3 2.3 2.3]]
  ...

This way the machine learning program knows to consider the coordinate vector as its own feature, not as a set of different features. So the actual shape might be (33000,3) rather than (33000,13) Is this possible?
I've tried dstack, concatenate, stack, etc. All have the issue that "the axis must match exactly".  In my case, the axis does not match. One feature has an axis of 10, and the others have either no axis (33000,) or 1 axis (33000,1) if you force it to have an axis. I'm not sure if there is a numpy array fact I'm missing or if this just might not be possible.

Which ML algorithm are you using? Can it make sense of a vector of ten values?

I'm using pytoch so torch.nn, The ML program is pretty simple
       " torch.nn.Linear(3,64),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),

        torch.nn.Linear(64,64),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),

        torch.nn.Linear(64,1),
        torch.nn.Sigmoid()".          

So I'm not sure if it can make sense of a vector of 10 values. I'm new to Machine Learning. If you know that it cannot, or know of one that could. I would appreciate the help.

Being quite newbie myself, I understand that you are essentially running a lot of regressors, i.e. you want to find coefficients that multiply each feature. So features should be a number.  I don't see why would it be a problem to one-hot encode the coordinates; finding how they are related is the job of the hidden layers. Maybe you could "help them" adding new features that contain information about all the coordinates, like principal components or the size of the vector, just to say something, but be careful about redundancies.
